# Revert back to factory settings Windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, boot, bootloader

After 4 years I now want to revert my computer back to the original Windows 7 install as it's getting slow and just want a fresh start.

My computer had originally a vista operating on the computer which I don't want back and are the disks that came with my computer.

Can I make a bootdisk from my windows 7 installation so when boot from it will offer me the choice to revert to factory settings

Thanks

Comment: How did Windows 7 get on your machine? If not at a factory, then there are no "factory settings" for Windows 7 for your machine. If you installed it and didn't take a backup, then you'll have to install it again. If there was an easier way to do it, you would have done it that way the first time.

Comment: @JohnnyQ - Format your HDD then install Windows 7 on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a boot cd/dvd from Your OS already installed on computer. You will need a bootable dvd with win 7 OS on it.And with that You can make a clean install.